# Meteor (v0.5.7) with Meteor_angularjs (v1.2.0) generates 'html##html_attributes##' tag within body tag

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I would like to know how to solve this issue which Meteor (v0.5.7) with Meteor_angularjs(v1.2.0) generates 'html##html_attributes##' tag within body tag.

If I use Meteor(v0.5.6) with Meteor_angularjs(v1.2.0), this issue doesn't happen.
So I think some generating code in Meteor(v0.5.7) has affected Meteor_angularjs.

This case is like this:

```
<html>
<head>…</head>
<body>
    <html##html_attributes##>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore/underscore.js?47479149fe12fc56685a9de90c5a9903390cb451"></script>
    ...
    (generated code by Meteor) 
    ...
    </html##html_attributes##>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see this issue with todos from Meteor_angularjs (v1.2.0) with Meteor (v0.5.7).

Avoiding this issue, I'm using Meteor (v0.5.6) currently for testing an integration of Meteor and Angular.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report. Have you considered submitting one to Meteor on github? https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/new

Comment: Rahul, thank you for your advise. I will submit this to the link you mentioned!

Comment: Here's the report link.
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/793

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is to run it with meteorite. Using Meteor always causes these issues for me. Here's how to fix:

1. Install meteorite: `sudo npm install -g meteorite`
2. CD into your directory:
   `cd myproject`
3. Now, instead of running meteor, run mrt for
   everything! Add the package: `mrt add angularjs` will automatically
   download and add the package.
4. Now, run your project with meteorite:
   `mrt`

That should fix your problem.

Comment: This may not fix the problem... I just suddenly started getting it